# Concat multiple videos FFMPEG 0.1 second after?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am precutting several videos ahead of time to be roughly 2 seconds long. The first one is 2s. The second one is 1.99s. So that in total they are 4s assuming the second clip will start .1s after the second one.

The reason for this is shown in a quick video I made showcasing the timeline I built https://cl.ly/b0d91eb087e7.

For the user, my opinion is that this is the most intuitive. The next clip will always start 0.1s after the previous.

First Clip 2s

```
ffmpeg
        -i "image.png"
        -i "video-bg.png"
        -f lavfi
        -i color=c=#ffffff:s=1080x1080
        -filter_complex "
          [0:v]scale=922.226355701817:1745.5544426956646[out0],
          [1:v]scale=1080:1080[out1],
          [2:v][out1]overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,0,2)'[out3],
          [out3][out0]overlay=-113.12530740270425:61.811417942481036:enable='between(t,0,2)'[vid]
        "
        -map "[vid]"
        -vcodec libx264
        -vb 20M
        -crf 17
        -preset veryfast
        -pix_fmt yuv420p
        -t 00:00:02.00
        out.mp4
```

Second Clip 1.99s

```
ffmpeg
        -i "image2.png"
        -i "video-bg.png"
        -f lavfi
        -i color=c=#ffffff:s=1080x1080
        -filter_complex "
          [0:v]scale=1270.8427528974103:1142.2750035770496[out0],
          [1:v]scale=1080:1080[out1],
          [2:v][out1]overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,0,6)'[out3],
          [out3][out0]overlay=-87.75274650343397:-24.4787400289741:enable='between(t,0,6)'[vid]
        "
        -map "[vid]"
        -vcodec libx264
        -vb 20M
        -crf 17
        -preset veryfast
        -pix_fmt yuv420p
        -t 00:00:01.99
        out2.mp4
```

I want to concatenate the first and second clip so that its 4 seconds long. The first clip should be between 0s-2s then the second clip should start from 2.1s-4s.

Here is what I have but the problem is that it starts the second clip at 2s instead of 2.1s.

```
ffmpeg -i out1.mp4 -i out2.mp4 -filter_complex "[0][1]concat=n=2:v=1[v]" -map "[v]" final.mp4
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`ffmpeg -i out1.mp4 -i out2.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=1080x1080,trim=start=0:end=2[one];color=black:s=1080x1080:r=24:d=0.1[b0];[1:v]scale=1080x1080,trim=start=0:end=1.9[two];[one][b0][two]concat=n=3:v=1[v]" -map "[v]" final.mp4`

The scales (and s in the blank in-between) make sure that they are the same scale or the filter will fail, the trims ensure that clip 1 is 2 seconds and clip 2 is 1.9 seconds (to add up to 4 but these can be removed if length is irrelevant) the color= is the color of the gap, the r= is the framerate of the gap (note - I had issues when this didn't match the input framerate), d= is the duration of the gap and must be proceeded by 0. for sub-second durations, the `[one][b0][two]` part is the order of the clips

most of this was adapted from the answer here: https://superuser.com/a/1064592