# concatenate mp4 videos starting at fixed times

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I have a few videos I want to concatenate into one file.

I can do that following the instructions here:
https://superuser.com/a/1059261/3189

However, this puts the videos 'back to back'.  I want to insert a gap between the videos and have each video start on a new second (e.g `2:00` not `2:01`).

Someone had the same problem for audio ([FFmpeg - Concenating audio files with spacing](https://superuser.com/questions/931303/ffmpeg-concenating-audio-files-with-spacing)), and a solution was to create a blank audio file and insert it between the tracks.

However, this does not work for my problem as I need each track to start on a rounded second.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a 2-Step process for each clip, plus some preparation

Preparation: Create 1s silent black video by using /dev/zero as input with exactly same codec settings as the clips

Per Video (assuming video is 34.56 secs long):

Write concat file `/path/to/temp.ffconcat`

```
file '/path/to/clip.mp4'
file '/path/to/blacksilence.mp4'
```

Concatenate

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i /path/to/temp.ffconcat -c copy -to 35 /path/to/fullsecond-clip.mp4
```

Now your Video is prolonged to a round second - repeat this with all clips and you can just play them out one after the other.

Comment: Using the [color source filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#color) is better than `/dev/zero` because it works on all platforms.

Comment: How do I make the silent black video with the same codec setting?  I've googled to no avail.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Thanks - I didn't know this one. Anything similar for the sound?

Comment: @jedierikb Post the detailed parameters with which you create your videos and I can up an example for you.

Comment: @EugenRieck Yes, [anullsrc](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#anullsrc) or [aevalsrc](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#aevalsrc).

Comment: @EugenRieck http://superuser.com/questions/1150371/concat-mp4-with-blank-video