# concat mp4 with blank video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-conversion, gstreamer

I want to concatenate 5 seconds of blank/black video to the end of different videos I download from net.  The process I have for doing this is not working.

First I use `ffprobe` to the dimensions of the video (let's say it turns out to be 640x480). Then I create my blank video as so:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=color=black -t 5 -s 640x480 blank.mp4
```

The resultant video, `blank.mp4`, plays back as a 5 second blank video as expected.

Then I concatenate the videos as so:

```
ffmpeg -i random.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts a.ts
ffmpeg -i blank.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts b.ts
ffmpeg -i concat:a.ts|b.ts -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc final.mp4
```

*Now, it is worth noting: I have cribbed this together with snippets from all over the web / stackoverflow, and am pretty sure it is not right.  In fact, I know it is not right because...*

The resultant video, `final.mp4`, seems *almost* right. But during playback, once the playhead enters the end of the video into the 5 seconds of black, the video can then no longer seek to earlier in the video successfully.  Instead the video remains black (although I can hear the audio).

Suggestions?  I am looking for a general solution that will work with various mp4 files I find on the net.  Thank you!

---

helpful, but requires creating a large blank video with a longer duration than the source video...
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36786271/62255

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i random.mp4 -f lavfi -i color=s=640x480:d=5 -filter_complex [0:v][1]concat -af [0]apad -shortest out.mp4
```

Comment: `no matches found: [0:v][1]concat`

Comment: Show the full console output.

Comment: Alas, that is the full console output.

Comment: & if I've your attention and good grace, how would I add blank audio as well? (which I've since discovered is needed for concat with other videos to ensure synced audio and video)?

Comment: The full output has the banner and input and output details. Add `-report` to your command and run. A text file will be generated. Post that. Let's handle audio after that.

Comment: The `[0:v][1]concat` had to be placed into quotes and it worked. :-P

Comment: You can use default color size and scale2ref filter to match the main video width & height. Somewhat lazier than using `ffprobe`.